# eclipse simple bluetooth project

Tags: android, eclipse, bluetooth

Recently I started a project with a pic and an hc-05 Bluetooth module, which I would like to control with my android phone.

My phone should send a Byte value, controlled by a slider, to the Bluetooth module.
Additionally the phone should automatically select the HC-05.

So my question is: Do you have an easy project (not as big as the Bluetooth chat sample of eclipse) which is simple to understand and simple to modify to my specifications (like described above)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

check this links :

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/BluetoothChat/index.html

http://luugiathuy.com/2011/02/android-java-bluetooth/

http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/bluetooth/bluetoothadapter/android-bluetooth-example/

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-quick-look-bluetoothadapter--mobile-7813

good luck